# Trying to create SSH connection using Gitlab CI, Error : SSH Permission denied (publickey,password)

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Repository on GitLab and a Private VPS. What I'm trying to do is when I push to the repository I need GitLab/ci script to connect VPS server.
What I have tried is

1. log in to VPS and generate SSH keys using `ssh-keygen`
2. Copy private key to **Gitlab** > **Settings** > **CI/CD** > **Variables** > **SSH_PRIVATE_KEY**
3. Copy public key to **Gitlab** > **User Preferences** > **SSH Keys**
4. And push commits using following script in **gitlab.ci**

```
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apk add openssh-client )'
    # Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    # add ssh key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > key
    - chmod 600 key
    - ssh-add key
    # make dirs
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan -t rsa 1.2.3.4.5 > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    # Remove
    - rm key
  script:
    - ssh user@1.2.3.4.5
```

**=> PS: 1.2.3.4.5 is not a real IP address I just changed it as an example.**

5. What I am getting in pipeline is `user@1.2.3.4.5 : Permission denied (publickey,password).`

**=> **PS: My branches or tags are not protected or private****

Comment: And you have added your newly generated key to `authorized_keys`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the script test, use:

```
ssh -Tv user@1.2.3.4.5
```

That way, you will see if the file named '`key`' is used or not.

If it is actually named 'key' (instead of the default `id_rsa` for instance), you would need a ~/.ssh/config file to reference it:

```
Host destination
  Hosname 1.2.3.4.5
  User user
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key
```

But in the case, the URL call would be:

```
ssh -Tv destination
```